# "public/index.php" is writeable by group, in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this php error with an error code 500 on my browser

> [error] [client XX.XX.XX.XX] SoftException in Application.cpp:254:
> File "/root_path/public/index.php" is writeable by group

What does this error mean and how can I fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Change the file permissions from '0664' to '0644'

Comment: Thanks its resolved my problem :)

Comment: I have problems with this. Laravel 5.2 doesn't show me the errors (when I have it) with there permissions.

Comment: I had the same problem so I googled and landed here.. So I tried.. Didn"t work for me as my file was in a sub-folder (from root). Had to change the sub-folder too  to 755...Then it worked... If it can help..

Comment: @GONG  You solved my issue.

Comment: What if I want it writeable by group?