# Laravel Fresh Install 500 Error on GoDaddy VPS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vps, laravel-5.4

I have installed a fresh Laravel 5.4 on a Godaddy VPS. It's returning a 500 error. I've done the symlink `ln -s myapp.com/public public_html` but it's still returning the 500 error. I've also changed the permissions to `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` to `777` but it's still the same. This is my second Laravel app in the same VPS and the first one is working fine. They're in 2 different directories/accounts `home/usr1` and `home/usr2` so I think it's not a collision. Or is it? I need help. It's already consumed so much of my time just searching and drifting from page to page just looking for a solution but I've found none.

I just found that there is a cPanel Log (how noob of me) and the it says

`[Tue Apr 04 05:58:29.616821 2017] [:error] [pid 31803] [client 112.210.57.133:53210] SoftException in Application.cpp:261: File "/home/networkmarketing/networkmarketingfortuneformula.com/public/index.php" is writeable by group`

`[Tue Apr 04 05:58:29.613420 2017] [:error] [pid 31803] [client 112.210.57.133:53210] SoftException in Application.cpp:261: File "/home/networkmarketing/networkmarketingfortuneformula.com/public/index.php" is writeable by group`

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: And to the upward direction.

Comment: @linktoahref 
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@networkmarketingfortuneformula.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Check if there is any error logs in `storage/logs` directory

Comment: @linktoahref it's empty

Comment: check into apache error log. It might help you.

Comment: @PaladiN where can i find that? sorry i'm not that well versed with servers

Comment: if you are using ubuntu as your server OS and apache then it is located in your `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @PaladiN i think i'm using linux server. are they the same?

Comment: Try composer install.

Comment: are u uploaded files as zip and extracted it ?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan `Nothing to install or update`

Comment: Did you check your appache error log? Can you show what it contain?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan @PaladiN do i access `/var/log/apache2/error.log` in putty? I can only get up to `/var/log` folder. there is no `apache2` folder

Comment: have you given permission to the storage folder??

Comment: Maybe you use nginix? Check do you have nginix folder in /var/log

Comment: @SayantanDas yeah. `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` changed to 777

Comment: @VaheGalstyan there is no `nginix` folder. there is `httpd` though and i remember it's related to `apache`.

Comment: Go  to httpd and check error logs.

Comment: @VaheGalstyan `~bash: cd: httpd: Permission denied`

Comment: Connect with help center, you have not permission to see logs, maybe help center can show you error logs.

Comment: @VaheGalstyan godaddy support? okay

Comment: I can access `laravelapp/public/css`  using `myapp.com/css`, and other files/folders in laravel's public folder

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I've updated the question I've found the cpanel error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why after a fresh install the permissions are messed up but I changed the permissions of `/laravelapp`, `/laravelapp/public`, and `/laravelapp/public/index.php` to `755`.

It's now working perfectly.

Comment: You are amazing! , been trying to solve this for 2 hours .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change permission to 755, if you have not access for that connect to support. [Permission problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700821/public-index-php-is-writeable-by-group-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Make you have the correct php version and all php modules you need installed.

I was missing mbstring and i had php 5.5 selected. upgrading to php 7 and installing all required modules worked.

Comment: Laravel needs atleast PHP 5.6.4 but easyapache only has 5.6.3 as it's latest available version.

Comment: just upgraded to PHP 7.1 and it's still showing the same error